# cómo puedo crear una función que me permita invertir el orden de las filas de una matriz en Python?

Tags: python, numpy

He creado la siguiente matriz:

```
A6=np.matrix(([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]))
```

e hice el respectivo ejercicio de invertir las filas, pero ahora quiero hacerlo mediante una función

```
B = A6[::-1,:]
print(B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```
a6=([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16])

print(a6)

def invertir_matriz(mat):
    return list(reversed(mat))

print(invertir_matriz(a6))
```

Invierte los elementos de la matriz, respetando la secuencia de los mismos. Si tenemos una matriz `([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8])`, la función devuelve `([7,8][5,6],[3,4],[1,2])`.

Saludos!!

Comment: Básicamente invierte los elementos de la matriz, respetando la secuencia de los mismos. Si tenemos una matriz ( [1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]) , la función devuelve ( [7,8][5,6],[3,4],[1,2]).

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y agrega lo que mencionas en tu comentario _en la respuesta_.